# How do i solve an error on linear equation by python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

Today, I've made a simple project about solving simple equation by python.
like this

```
linear="30=10x-20"
#c=bx+a or a+bx=c
a=0
c=0
b=0 
split=linear.split("=")
if len(split[0])==1 or len(split[1])==1 :
 c=int(split[0]) if len(split[0])==1 else int(split[1])
if len(split[0])>1 or len(split[1])>1  :
 b=int(split[0][:linear.index("x")]) if len(split[0])>1 else int(split[1][:linear.index("x")])
 a=int(split[0][linear.index("x")+1:] if len(split[0])>1 elseint(split[1[linear.index("x")+1:]))

total=(c-a)/b
print(total)
```

So, it separates the string between "=" first. Then, it analyzes the part of
separation to get the values of a,b,c. After that, I got the error. How do i fix this ?
thank you.

> a=int(split[0][linear.index("x")+1:] if len(split[0])>1 else int(split[1][linear.index("x")+1:]))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: It's not really clear what your code is doing.  Why are you checking to see if len(anything) is 1?  This gives you the length of the string, and in the above, your string lengths after the split will be 2 and 6.

You really want to use a regular expressions here.  You have two regular expressions, one for the first form and one for the second, and you can easily check which it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if and else statements are confusing may be because of that you may be having this error. The things would be simpler if you learn regex in python.

I have tried with the given linear equation. Please use it as a reference.

```
import re

equation = '30=10x-20'

#Checking 'c = bx+a' or 'bx+a = c'
x = re.match('[0-9]+=[0-9]+x+?-?[0-9]+',equation)

if x:
    #print('True')
    output_1 = equation.split('=')
    c = int(output_1[0])
    print('c = ',c)
    # checking the operator between bx and a
    #rhs = '[0-9]+x+?[0-9]+'
    y = re.match('[0-9]+x-?[0-9]+',output_1[1])

   if y:
        #filter_b = ['x']
        output_2 = output_1[1].split('-')
        a = int(output_2[1])
        b = int(output_2[0].replace("x",""))
        print('a = ',a)
        print('b = ',b)
    
  else:
       print('False')

else:
    print('False')
```

answer:

```
c =  30
a =  20
b =  10
```